# serverless webpack warning could not determine version of module

Tags: webpack, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a typescript serverless project with serverless-webpack. It uses such modules as knex (sql query builder), pg, ioredis. Since these are designed to work server-side, there were some issues with bundling those with webpack, so I listed those as externals in webpack config.

Everything works but every time when packaging I get `WARNING Could not determine version of module X` for each of those.

Can someone explain me, what is the real underlying issue, which causes that and how can it be fixed to make things cleaner?

Comment: Did you actually check that module is in package.json dependencies. That might be coming from some other packages. I had the issue with express.js package. Later realised that it wasnt in package.json

Comment: I’m using a monorepo with lerna so it’s a bit more complicated. but it still should be resolved ok, all the dependencies are listed either in root or in local package. json

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Huber not yet, unfortunately. Would still appreciate insights on this.

Comment: @TristanTzara I moved away from serverless-webpack and got monorepo with serverless working for my use case, with serverless-jetpack and serverless-scriptable-plugin.